# sass/gulp-sass remains silent on certain errors (invalid properties)

Tags: error-handling, sass, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

Yep, sass in my gulpfile (gulp@3.9.1) reports many errors (and keeps continuing the watch, just as it should...), but not errors like these:

```js
=clearfix()
    &:after
        content: ""
        display: table
        clear both
```

`content` and `display` make it correctly into the actual class (where the mixin is referenced), but `clear` doesn't (because I missed the colon). This is a syntax error (so it's not like `rareproperty: 42px;` handled gracefully). → still: **No errors seen, no interruption.**

My gulp task:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {

    return gulp.src(src.scssMaster)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(  sass({
                    debugInfo   : true,
                    lineNumbers : true,
                    outputStyle: 'expanded'
                })
                .on('error', function(err){
                    gutil.log(err);    // stackoverflow.com/a/30742014/444255
                    this.emit('end');
                })
            )
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['iOS >= 5', 'ie 8', 'Firefox > 2'],
            cascade:   true,
            remove:    true
        }))
        .pipe(rename('lznet.css'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(src.cssDir))

        .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
        .on('end', () => gutil.log('sass thing done'));
});
```

Mille grazie ❤

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is a syntax error → still: No errors seen, no interruption.

It's not a syntax error at all. Take this example:

```
.foo
  color: blue
  clear both
```

This compiles to the following CSS:

```
.foo {
  color: blue; 
}
```

It certainly **looks like** the error of the wrongly specified `clear both` property is silently ignored. What is actually happening is that you have defined a nested `.foo clear both` selector. But since your `.foo clear both` selector is **empty** it is optimized away by the SASS compiler.

This becomes clear when you look at what happens with another SASS example:

```
.foo
  color: blue
  clear both
    color: red
```

This compiles to the following CSS:

```
.foo {
  color: blue; 
}
.foo clear both {
  color: red; 
}
```

Now the `.foo clear both` selector isn't empty and the CSS is no longer optimized away by the compiler.

SASS doesn't know or care about the fact that there isn't actually a `clear` or `both` element in any of the HTML specifications. This is a feature and not a bug since:

- Elements can get added and removed from HTML. This would make changes to SASS necessary any time a new HTML version is standardized.
- You can already define [custom HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5) (although in this case `clear` and `both` wouldn't be valid names even for web components).
- CSS (and therefore SASS) is in no way limited to HTML. You can also [use CSS to style XML documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279240/how-can-i-style-xml-with-css-for-viewing-in-a-browser-without-first-transforming) which obviously let you define custom elements like `clear` or `both`.

Comment: outstanding answer 